# Combinacion de queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos queries, que entregan valores distintos, pero utilizan la misma sintaxis casi, solo diferenciandose por un `and`.

```
select
    year(Fecha_factura) as Anio,
    month(Fecha_factura) as Mes,
    floor(sum(Venta_neta)) as Total_general
from Ventas
where Fecha_Factura >= '20200101'
group by year(Fecha_factura),month(Fecha_factura)
order by year(Fecha_factura),month(Fecha_factura)
```

Y la segunda query es esta:

```
select
        year(Fecha_factura) as Anio,
        month(Fecha_factura) as Mes,
        floor(sum(Venta_neta)) as Total_al_dia
    from Ventas
    where Fecha_Factura >= '20200101'
        and day(Fecha_Factura) < day(getdate())
    group by year(Fecha_factura),month(Fecha_factura)
    order by year(Fecha_factura),month(Fecha_factura)
```

Como pueden ver, la unica diferencia entre las dos es por el `and day(Fecha_Factura) < day(getdate())`. Entonces yo me pregunto, habra una forma de poder unir estas dos queries y en una sola consulta entregar los valores que necesito?

O sea, entregarme el listado de los años, meses, valor total y valor hasta el dia anterior.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es necesario hacer 2 consultas. En la primera ya tienes todos los datos que necesitas para obtener la segunda. Solo tienes que hacer un agregado condicional.

```
SELECT
        YEAR( Fecha_factura)        as Anio,
        MONTH( Fecha_factura)       as Mes,
        FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(Fecha_Factura) < DAY(GETDATE()) 
                       THEN Venta_neta 
                       ELSE 0 END)) as Total_al_dia,
        FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta))      as Total_general
FROM Ventas
WHERE Fecha_Factura >= '20200101'
GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha_factura),MONTH(Fecha_factura)
ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura),MONTH(Fecha_factura);
```

Comment: Excelente, me sirvio de una, muchas gracias! Ademas aprendi mas con esta explicacion, no tenia idea que se podian ocupar las condicionales asi.

Comment: Luis Cazares, me anclo a eta pregunta para preguntar algo extra. Como podria en esta misma query, restar Total_general del mes actual menos Total_general del mes anterior, correlativamente? O sea, mes 1 - mes 2, mes 2 - mes 3, mes 3 - mes 4.... etc. Estoy viendo como hacerlo en un case, pero no me resulta

Comment: Tienes que usar la función LAG(), pero creo que sería bueno que abrieras otra pregunta con datos de prueba e indicando que pasa al cambiar de año.

Comment: Luis, lo que necesito es de lo generado en FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) as `Total_general`, onda `FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta))` del mes actual - `FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta))` del mes anterior

Comment: Luis Cazares, pude resolver como agregar la diferencia que buscaba! Utilice este parametro en mi query y funciono:
`FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) - LEAD(FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta))) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura) DESC, MONTH(Fecha_factura) DESC)`

Comment: Sí puedo, haz otra pregunta con datos de prueba, resultados esperados e indicando que pasa al cambiar de año..

Comment: Estimado, duda. A que se refiere en el caso de cambiar el año?

Comment: Hay veces en que se requiere que enero haga referencia a diciembre del año anterior y hay veces en que se debe de tomar como algo totalmente independiente. Por eso es la pregunta.